# Load all images from folder and roll them in JS slider with Laravel framework

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, slideshow

What is the best way to roll all images from folder in JS slider with **Laravel** framework ?  This is current code with hard-coded image paths:

```
  var i =0;
  var images = [
    'images/sliders/background_slider/2.jpg',
    'images/sliders/background_slider/3.jpg',
    'images/sliders/background_slider/1.jpg',
    'images/sliders/background_slider/4.jpg',
    'images/sliders/background_slider/5.jpg'];
  var image = $('#slideit');
  image.css('background-image', 'url(images/sliders/background_slider/1.jpg)');
  setInterval(function(){
   image.fadeOut(200, function () {
   image.css('background-image', 'url(' + images [i++] +')');
   image.fadeIn(1000);
   });
   if(i == images.length)
    i = 0;
  }, 5000);
 });
```

This code works well, but my idea is to have an option to easy manage this pictures without touching the code. I have tried to create an PHP variable with all paths of images and then to use it in JS with json_encode function but this doesn't work. Also, when i load these paths in JS variable, i can easily see them in source view in every browser and i think, that's not a good idea from security point of view.

So, what's the best way to do that ?

Thanks in advance!

D.T.

Answer (score 0):

You can't hide the variable if you want to use it in client side JS. It would be the same as hard coding the array, with the only difference that it will be rendered using server side script in order to make it dynamic.

So, if your php variable is $images, it should look something like this:

```
$images = [
'images/sliders/background_slider/2.jpg',
'images/sliders/background_slider/3.jpg',
'images/sliders/background_slider/1.jpg',
'images/sliders/background_slider/4.jpg',
'images/sliders/background_slider/5.jpg'];
```

And to pass it to your view, you can do:

```
$data['images'] = json_encode($images);
```

Then, in the view, instead of hard coding the values, you'll get them from your php variable. Convert the json string back:

```
var images = JSON.parse('<?=$images?>');
```

And, to set the first image as background:

```
image.css('background-image', 'url('+images[0]+')');
```

**UPDATE**:

I just noticed you are counting the elements of the image array, which you won't be able to do with the object generated after `JSON.parse`. Instead, you can create an array of keys for every object element and count that instead.

```
images_keys= $.map(images, function(v, i){
    return i;
});
```

And wherever you need `images.length`, you can go with `images_keys`. For everything else, you can use the images object itself.